# awk hostname and ip address from log files when the column numbers are different

Tags: awk, text-formatting

This is my sample file. Actual data has way more data in it.

```
wolf@linux:~$ more log*
::::::::::::::
log1.csv
::::::::::::::
hostname,sn,type,ip,random
abc,a11,zzz,192.168.168.168,rrr
def,e16,yyy,192.168.168.169,fff
ghi,k16,yyy,192.168.168.170,ggg
::::::::::::::
log2.csv
::::::::::::::
hostname,sn,ip,random
abc,a11,192.168.168.168,rrr
def,e16,192.168.168.169,fff
ghi,k16,yyy,192.168.168.170,ggg
wolf@linux:~$
```

Certain data such as hostname is always located in the 1st column. So, it's easy to get them with `awk -F, '{print $1}'`

```
wolf@linux:~$ awk -F, '{print $1, $4}' log*
hostname ip
abc 192.168.168.168
def 192.168.168.169
ghi 192.168.168.170
hostname random
abc rrr
def fff
ghi 192.168.168.170
wolf@linux:~$
```

The problem is data such IP Address is located in different column depending on the data in the log files.

How do I use grep to get only column for hostname & IP?

```
wolf@linux:~$ awk -F, '/def/ {print $1, $4}' log*
def 192.168.168.169
def fff
wolf@linux:~$
```

.

```
wolf@linux:~$ awk -F, '/def/ {print $1, $3}' log*
def yyy
def 192.168.168.169
wolf@linux:~$
```

Desired Output

```
def 192.168.168.169
def 192.168.168.169
```

Comment: so what the header useful for when fields doesn't follow headers?  if it is, I have a solution ready to post.

Comment: `log2.csv` doesn't **really** have the line `ghi,k16,yyy,192.168.168.170,ggg` in it does it?

Answer (score 3):

if the data fields follows the header line in each file, you could do:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i=="ip") break; next }
               { print $1, $i }' log*.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

best I come with :

```
awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ( $i ~ /^192/ ) printf "%s %s\n",$1,$i ;}'
```

where

- I suppose IP begin with 192
- <s>hostname is on field 1</s> stated in question
- if two or more IP, line will be printed twice.

you can use `if ( $i ~ /^[0-9\.]+$/ )` to further restrict to IP (note that it will also catch 12)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvcut -c hostname,ip log1.csv
hostname,ip
abc,192.168.168.168
def,192.168.168.169
ghi,192.168.168.170
$ csvcut -c hostname,ip log2.csv
hostname,ip
abc,192.168.168.168
def,192.168.168.169
ghi,yyy
```

The `csvcut` command works a bit like the standard `cut` command, but can use the header information to extract named columns.

Note that this relies on the headers in each file actually being correct.

Comment: Second file the `yyy` is in the wrong place and breaks anything that depends on the headers for accuracy

Comment: @roaima The fact that the second column of the second file isn't properly quoted (or that the output is messed up in other unexpected way) is an issue with the program that produces the output.

Comment: Yes. And as I understand the question that's what the OP is trying to address

Answer (score 1):

When you have files with headers it's often best to first create the mapping of header tags (names) to the field (column) order as stored in the array `f[]` below and then you can simply get the field values by dereferencing the array indexed by the field name. That way your script will work no matter what order the columns are in in each input file:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
FNR==1 {
    delete f
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
    next
}
$(f["hostname"]) == h { print $(f["hostname"]), $(f["ip"]) }
```

```
$ awk -v h='def' -f tst.awk log*.csv
def 192.168.168.169
def 192.168.168.169
```